# Inverting Matrix transformations on an image

Tags: image-processing

I'm hoping to work out how to improve image quality by doing a Matrix transformation on an image which essentially 'undoes' the softening/motion blur of an image.

If I was to apply transform A to a sharp image, what transform B would get me back to the original image if A is the following:

```
0 1 0
0 1 0
0 1 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The only way to achieve such goal, would be depending on the transform.

Imagine a case a very basic(and perhaps stupid) blurring function. It applies to image and converts all pixels 127, 128, 129 from values in range of [0-255]. To inverse this filter we have to be able to map values back. However, we just lost the information. Example is both pixel values 1 and 5 converted to 127. Now, with no information of their previous values, when we read the value of converted pixel 127, should we convert it to 1 or 5? We don't know.

Now, keeping in the mind some transforms are one way ticket. There are better scenarios. For example, linear transforms such as rotation of an image can be completely reversed by basically transforming image with the inverse or rotation matrix.

> A^(-1)=A^(T)

where A is rotation matrix.

So basically, transform is inversed when:

> AIA^(T)

where I is image and A is rotation matrix.

Therefore, there are two things you need to have to be able to reverse the transform an image. Your transform must be mathematically reversable. And then you need to apply tranform which is mathematically inverse of your transform function.

There are of course, ways you can try to sharpen an image without exactly transforming back, if they are ok for you here are some these techniques for dealing with blur images;

High pass filtering, simple but a classic: http://northstar-www.dartmouth.edu/doc/idl/html_6.2/Sharpening_an_Image.html

Deconvolution: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deconvolution

Variational methods(Methods based on calculus of variations ) : http://www.math.ucla.edu/~bertozzi/papers/moellerpaper.pdf

More can be found in literature.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying the requirements. What I probably needed to ask is, is a simple blur function such as the one above (which averages the pixel above, the current pixel, and the pixel below) reversible? I'm assuming here that the tonal precision in the image (16 bit rather than 8 bit) is sufficient to handle rounding errors (if extreme, as you showed, this can be irreversible).

My thoughts is that some function of the three pixels involved in the blur will get you back to the starting point, but I haven't studied this field enough to know instinctively what it is.

Comment: No, not really. How does average filtering works? It takes a convolution matrix and filters image with it. For the simplicity let's say this filter is a one row and 3 columns sized. Meaning takes three pixels and averages their intesity and save it to pixel it operating on. And let's say this value is 50. Now when you want to inverse, assume you know the filter applied, so you are looking at value 50 and thinking were they 51,50,49 or 0,50,100, etc. You can't really know, The only approach you can take is solving a set equations find original values which can hard depending on the situation